# @InjectMocks isnt actually injecting mocks

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

So i have a class that needs to be tested. Lets call it ClassToTest. It has a couple of Dao objects as fields.

```
Public class ClassToTest {

    @Autowired
    MyDao dao;

    void methodToTest() {
        dao.save(something);
    }
}
```

As you can see ClassToTest does not contain any constructor or setter and I am using spring to autowire the fields.

Now, I have a base test class with all the dependencies that classToTest requires:

```
public abstract BaseTest {

    @Mock
    MyDao dao;

}
```

And the testClass extends this BaseTest class :

```
public class TestClass extends BaseTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest();

    @Before 
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        classToTest.methodToTest();
    }
}
```

This results in a null pointer exception when the save happens. However, if i change setup method to this :

```
@Before 
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    classToTest.dao = dao;
}
```

the test passes.

My understanding was that when a class does not have a constructor or a setter, InjectMocks would inject the mocks by using field injection. Why is that not happening here?

Comment: I reproduced your test case exactly (after fixing the compilation errors), and it works fine. So the problem is in soething you're not showing. Provide a complete, compilable, runnable test case, containing all the classes needed.

Comment: Its too big and complicated to be posted here. That's why i simplified it. What version of mockito did u use?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that this is a bug in the 1.8.5 version that i was using : https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=229.

Upgrading 1.10 fixed the issue.

Comment: Not a bug ;) But a limitation when the feature was first introduced.